# Abelian varieties with endomorphism structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let me stick to principally polarised abelian varieties $X$ over $\mathbb C$.

I have seen several definitions of what it means for $X$ to have real multiplication by a totally real field $F$:

1. There is an embedding of rings $F \to \mathrm{End}(X)^s_\mathbb Q$, the elements fixed by the Rosatti involution. This is from *Complex abelian varieties*, by C. Birkenhage and H. Lange
2. There is an embedding of rings $\mathcal O_F \to \mathrm{End}(X)^s$, again, the elements fixed by the Rosatti involution, and where $\mathcal O_F$ is the ring of integers. This is, for example, in *Compactifications de l'espace de modules de Hilbert-Blumenthal* by M. Rapoport
3. There is an embedding of rings $\mathfrak o \to \mathrm{End}(X)^s$, where $\mathfrak o$ is an order in $F$. I didn't find this stated like this anywhere, but is the impression that I get from several papers on Humbert surfaces.

I have several question around this:

- Q1: Are definitions 1. and 3. equivalent? Maybe under the assumption that $[F:\mathbb Q] = \mathrm{dim} (X)$.
- Q2: I think that Definition 2 is stronger than Definition 1. Does this pose significant problems to reproduce the results of the mentioned paper by M. Rapoport?
- Q3: This is just a question to understand if I connect this well with the theory for abelian surfaces. Is it correct to say that an abelian surface $X$ has multiplication by $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{D_0})$ as in Definition 3, with the order being the unique one with conductor $f$, if and only if $[X]$ is in
  $$
  \bigcup_{f' \mid f} \mathcal H_{f'^2\Delta_0},
  $$
  where $\Delta_0$ is the discriminant of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ and the $\mathcal H_n$ are the Humbert surfaces?
- Q4: Consider definition 3', where we furthermore ask the embedding $\mathfrak o \to \mathrm{End}(X)$ to be primitive, i.e. $\mathrm{End}(X)/\mathfrak o$ has to be torsion-free as a $\mathbb Z$-module. Has someone proven that the locus of such abelian varieties in $\mathcal A_g$, for fixed $\mathfrak o$, is irreducible?
- Q5: This is a non-mathematical question, but I find the different notations in different papers about this topic and that of Humbert surfaces extremely confusing, and a lot of these papers start by recalling some definitions, which don't seem to match completely with each other, like this issue with what real multiplication means, or that, in *Humbert Surfaces and the Kummer Plane* by C. Birkenhage and H. Wilhelm the Humbert surfaces are reducible, while in *Lectures on Abelian varieties* by I. Dolgachev it is stated that the Humbert surfaces are irreducible, when working with principally polarized a.v., although their definition is the same (I think the key point is asking for primitive solutions but in any case, I didn't see this noted in any of the two references). Why are there so many differences and poorly defined notions?

Comment: Actually, Rapoport requires the degree of $F$ to equal $dim(A)$ whereas B&L don't. There is the same confusion regarding the definition of complex multiplication. Two different conventions arose in mathematics -- this is not uncommon. Rapoport requires the full ring of integers to act because that is what gives him a good moduli problem, which is what he is interested in.